# How is "craft()->fileCache" different from using cookies?

Tags: plugin-development, filecache, cookies

Just looking for a little clarification on the `craft()->fileCache` method...

Everybody already knows that when a cookie is set, that cookie only exists on the end-user's computer. No one else using the website can access that cookie.

But if I were to replace that cookie getter/setter with the `craft()->fileCache` getter/setter methods, is that data now available to everyone? Where a cookie is stored on the **client** machine, the `fileCache` data is stored on the **server**?

This is what I suspect is happening, just trying to be sure that I'm interpreting this correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct... `craft()->fileCache` will save to your `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder by default, which will have a .bin file that has a hash of the key you provided when calling `set()` and the contents will be a serialized version of the value you passed in.

Also worth noting that while `craft()->fileCache` still exists, as of Craft 2.0, it is simply a shortcut to `craft()->cache`, when the [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting is set to `file`.

Comment: Great, thanks Brad! To clarify further... if I use `fileCache` then I'm determining at the **plugin level** where the data will get saved, but if I just use `cache` it will default to wherever the website's **config file** specifies. Is that correct?

Comment: Yup... nailed it.